# JavaFX: Can't set items of TableView to FilteredList of its own items

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I am trying to set the items of a `TableView` to a `FilteredList` of its own items but I get an error doing so.

```
public class FilteredTableView<T> {

    private TableView<?> tableView;
    FilteredList<?> filteredData;

    public <T> FilteredTableView(TableView<T> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
        this.filteredData = new FilteredList<>(tableView.getItems(), s -> true);
        this.tableView.setItems(this.filteredData); // The method setItems(ObservableList<capture#4-of ?>) in the type TableView<capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (FilteredList<capture#5-of ?>)
    }

}
```

Is there a way to solve this without having to make a new `FilteredTableViewObjectX` class for every different Object I want to put in a different TableView? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your class is already parameterized with the type `T`, your `TableView` and `FilteredList` variables can refer to the same type.

Note that the method should **not** be parameterized, because then `T` in the method will refer to a different type variable than `T` in the class (leading to really interesting compile errors such as "Cannot convert from `TableView<T>` to `TableView<T>`").

```
public class FilteredTableView<T> {

    private TableView<T> tableView;
    FilteredList<T> filteredData;

    public FilteredTableView(TableView<T> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
        this.filteredData = new FilteredList<>(tableView.getItems(), s -> true);
        this.tableView.setItems(this.filteredData); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I remember seing that error earlier, but it is working now (using your answer) :)